# Downloading dynamic world full rasters (not just mode) over a geography

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-cover, google-earth-engine-python-api, download

I have been using the following Python script to download "modes" of the dynamic world dataset like this:

```
        mosaic = (
            ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1')
                #.select(dw_channels)
                .filterBounds(roi)
                .filterDate(date_start, date_end)
        ).mosaic()

        mosaic = mosaic.select("label")
        mosaic = mosaic.reduce(ee.Reducer.mode())

        url = mosaic.clip(roi).getDownloadURL({
            'name': 'dw', 
            'crs': 'EPSG:4326',
            'scale': 10,
            })
        _ = safe_urlretrieve(url, outpath)
```

I would like to do the same, but download the probability bands rather than the modes. How do I do this?

Comment: It's worth noting that you're taking the `mode()` after `mosaic()`, which means the mode does nothing.  Remove the `.mosaic()` if you actually want the mode.  Or take the mean of the probabilities, as the answer suggests.  Just don't `mosaic()` first.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply select the bands of interest and calculate a metric that summarises the probability values. For example, in this case I used the mean probability and then you can export the multiband image in the same way you exported your image in the OP.

```
// Get names of bands, excluding 'label'
var bands = mosaic.bandNames().slice(0,9,1);

// Select bands and calculate the mean probability by band.
var mosaic= mosaic.select(bands)
                  .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! 

One detail that may be helpful to future users is that you should multiply by 100 before downloading since .tif pixel values are integers and everything will be 0 if you dont, i.e.:

`mosaic= mosaic.select(bands).reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).multiply(ee.Number(100))`